# How to remove the extra details from the debug console?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to understand visual studio. I would like to only see "Hello my name is hamza" instead of all the details like file location and the message to automatically close the console.

> Hello my name is hamza
>
> C:\Users\Amir Hamza\Desktop\4th sem\oop\Home Practice\Learn 1\x64\Debug\Learn 1.exe (process 12036) exited with code 0.
>
> To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.
>
> Press any key to close this window . . .

Comment: Your program terminates when it has no more code to run, the message you get is here instead of the window closing.. if you don't want the program to close give a reason but using cin or getch() as waiting for user input

Comment: You need to be careful about this - for a small program, if you do not leave the console up, you may not even see it if it is a very simple program.  If all the program does is print something and exit, all you will see is a flash and the program has terminated.  Unless you can read at lightning speed, you won't even nnotice what has been printed.

Answer (score 2):

1,I suggest you could try to go on Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General,check "Automatically close the console when debugging stops"
[image]

And then click debug -> start without debugging

[image]

[image]

2,Or you can choose to add the following code:

```
system("pause");
```

And then click debug -> start debugging

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also call your .exe file from the command prompt (cmd.exe), but then it will show a new command prompt when your program exits.

Alternatively, you can prevent your program from exiting when it is finished, for example by waiting for a key press using the function [_getch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getch-getwch). Only after the user presses a key will your program terminate as before.